# No Log or Toast showing up when data exchaged in 2 classes in Android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve which spinner item is selected inside `spinnerSelects` class from `converter` class, but No logs or Taost file are showing. Why this is happening? and also can I pass the context of non-activity class `spinnerSelects` to another non-activity class like `converter` class ??

Below is my `spinnerSelects.java` class :

```
package com.gazzali.spinitmeow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class spinnerSelects implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    protected Spinner spinnerInputChoice, spinnerOutputChoice;
    protected ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapterInputChoice, adapterOutputChoice;

    private Context context;

    public Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    public spinnerSelects() {
        getContext();
    }

    public spinnerSelects(Spinner spinnerInputChoiceFromMain, Spinner spinnerOutputChoiceFromMain) {
        this.spinnerInputChoice = spinnerInputChoiceFromMain;
        this.spinnerOutputChoice = spinnerOutputChoiceFromMain;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param selectedMainChoice String retrieves Main Conversion spinner's type
     * @param contextFromMain Context retrieves context from MainActivity
     */
    public void setInputOutputSpinners(String selectedMainChoice, Context contextFromMain) {
        switch (selectedMainChoice)
        {
            case "Length": {
                adapterInputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(contextFromMain,
                        R.array.LengthChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapterOutputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(contextFromMain,
                        R.array.LengthChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                setInputOutputListenerAndDropDownAndAdapter();
            }
            break;

            case "Temperature": {
                adapterInputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(contextFromMain,
                        R.array.TemperatureChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                adapterOutputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(contextFromMain,
                        R.array.TemperatureChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                setInputOutputListenerAndDropDownAndAdapter();
            }
            break;

            case "Weight": {
                adapterInputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(contextFromMain,
                        R.array.WeightChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                adapterOutputChoice = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(contextFromMain,
                        R.array.WeightChoices_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

                setInputOutputListenerAndDropDownAndAdapter();

            }
            break;
        }
    }
    private void setInputOutputListenerAndDropDownAndAdapter() {

        adapterInputChoice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerInputChoice.setAdapter(adapterInputChoice);
        adapterOutputChoice.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerOutputChoice.setAdapter(adapterOutputChoice);

    }

    public Spinner getSpinnerInputChoice() {
        return spinnerInputChoice;
    }

    public Spinner getSpinnerOutputChoice() {
        return spinnerOutputChoice;
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

And `converter.java` class :

```
package com.gazzali.spinitmeow;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class converter {

    private Context contextInConverter;

    protected String selectedMainChoice, inputChoice, outputChoice;
    protected Spinner spinnerInputChoice, spinnerOutputChoice;



    public converter(Context contextFromMain, String selectedMainChoiceFromMain) {
        this.selectedMainChoice = selectedMainChoiceFromMain;
        /*Toast.makeText(contextFromMain, selectedMainChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        /*Log.i("Main Choice is", selectedMainChoice);*/
    }

    public void setInputOutputChoice(Spinner spinnerInputChoiceFromSpinnerSelects, Spinner spinnerOutputChoiceFromSpinnerSelcts){

        spinnerSelects spinnerSelectsInConverter = new spinnerSelects();
        spinnerInputChoice = spinnerSelectsInConverter.getSpinnerInputChoice();
        inputChoice = spinnerInputChoice.getSelectedItem().toString();

        contextInConverter = spinnerSelectsInConverter.getContext();

        /* No Toast or Log showing up */

        Toast.makeText(contextInConverter, inputChoice, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("Sub Choices are:", inputChoice);

    }
}
```

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any `converter` instantiation inside `spinnerSelects` class.

Looks like you are not calling your method hench you will not see any `Toast`.

You need to do something like this:

```
ConvertorClass convertor = new Convertor();
convertor.yourMethod();
```

Comment: I want to retrieve `spinnerSelects` 's methods to be retrieved inside `converter` class, So I think I don't need to initialize it to inside `spinnerSelects` class

Comment: I was mistaken then, are you calling `setInputOutputChoice` from anywhere?

Comment: Yeah, Still No Improvement

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 public converter(Context contextFromMain, String selectedMainChoiceFromMain) {
        this.selectedMainChoice = selectedMainChoiceFromMain;
          }
```

To

```
 public converter(Context contextFromMain, String selectedMainChoiceFromMain) {
        this.contextInConverter=    contextFromMain;   
this.selectedMainChoice = selectedMainChoiceFromMain;
                  }
```